# How to deploy keycloak to EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, keycloak, amazon-eks

I have a scenario where I want to deploy keycloak to an instance and whenever user accesses an application it should be redirected to that instance.

I'm using AWS's EKS to achieve this. Have created an EKS cluster and 2 instances of EC2 and configured to access EKS locally. But I'm not sure how to deploy keycloak to the cluster and redirect the users if not logged in.

I hope someone would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Keycloak Helm chart](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak)?

Comment: Thank you so much @ChinHuang It worked.